# Best way to implement "iOS Photos style" tiled image gallery

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, photo-gallery

I have an app that basically can be used to download, upload, and manage photos from various web services.

I want the image list view to look like the iOS Photos app but not quite sure what the best way to do that is.

I was thinking I could use NSMutableArray and subclass UIScrollView to create that functionality from scratch but I'd really like to use NSFetchedResultsController because some of the data related to the images are dynamically/asynchronously updated/inserted/deleted in Core Data.

Right now I've setup something pretty hacky.
I created an separate Core Data entity to hold relationships to 4 photos in each managed object and I made UITableView loop through them. Then cellforrow delegate would loop through the 4 photos in each table cell. This approach sucks because it's hard to delete and insert photos dynamically and I have to reconstruct relationships and reload the table each time an update is made.

I've looked at some other libraries that do this but I really want to understand what the most simple and efficient way to do this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the tile view, you can duplicate that using a `UITableView` or a `UIScrollView`.  If you want it to side scroll then a `UIScrollView` is the starting point.

If you want it to scroll vertically (which I recommend on iPhone) then use a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`.

As for the Core Data side, you are probably coming at this incorrect, you are trying to store UI state information (how many photos are in a cell) in core data.  Core Data should not care about how many images are in a cell.

### UITableViewCell

To use a `UITableView` you would create an array that contains all of your images.  You can then determine how many rows you need by dividing that array by the number of images per row.

From there you should subclass `UITableViewCell` and pass in the 4 images for that cell to draw.  Then it is a simple matter of adding 4 `UIImageView` instances to the custom cell and setting the images.

### UIScrollView

For a scrollview you crate a `UIImageView` for each image and then add them as subviews of the `UIScrollView`.  You would then set the frame of each `UIImageView` so that they are displayed in a grid.

If you find you have more images than you can hold in memory at once then you will need to deal with tiling, effectively paying attention to where the user is scrolling and filling in (via moving the offscreen image views) ahead of the edge the user is scrolling towards.  This is the same thing you get effectively for free with a `UITableView` via its queuing of cells.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, like I mentioned to @sosborn I was wondering if there was any way to use NSFetchedResultsController's didChangeObject:atIndexPath: so I won't have to reset and reload the entire table each time there is a change. In any case, I think I'll go with this for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you can but it requires calculating the indexPath offset and then reacting to it properly.  Can be a lot of work, especially with inserts and deletes but it can be done with a UITableView. In a scrollView design I would build my own context watcher instead.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this with a UITableView - you are over thinking it with the relationships.

For my solution I created a UITableViewCell subclass has four buttons as properties.

In my cellForRow method I figure out which four images belong to that row and then set the appropriate image for the appropriate button.

My images are in an array in my view controller. I populate the array in viewDidLoad. Whenever I add or delete an image from the managedObjectContext I repopulate the array and then reload the tableview. Reloading the tableview will rearrange the images in the cell appropriately.

Scrolling is smooth and the only drawback I have run into is that I would like the images to animate to their new positions when I delete one, but I do not think that I'll be able to pull that off with this setup.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have actually thought about this approach but I really liked how NSFetchedResultsController only updates/redraws the cell that's been changed rather then having the entire UITableView reload and I was wondering if there was anyway to really optimize it like that. This is a start though thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think a very nice implementation is [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/).

It is easy to extends, has nice reordering (see the springboard demo) and it reuses the cell.

If you ever implemented a TableViewDelegate, you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Three20 photo viewer. The project is on github. Also, there's a nice tutorial for the photo viewer [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer)

Comment: I'd rather not use three20 because I really think it's overkill for this specific project and I want to understand the logic in building this rather than slapping a library on. If all else fails I guess I'll have try to look through the three20 code line by line and try to make sense of it on my own.

Comment: I recommend against Three20.  It is a huge block of code that re-implements (badly) functionality that you get for free as part of iOS.

Comment: I have a similar opinion as @MarcusS.Zarra: Three20 first seems to give you so much for free — but later you will have to pay a lot, once some of your ideas doesn't fit 100% into the Three20 assumptions.